# Frequent freezes w Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, debugging

My laptop freezes about every day, and I am using REISUB to recover.  I tend to have Firefox open with a few tabs, maybe Youtube for music, Foxit PDF, Libre Office Writer, Spyder for Python, file browser, Clementine music player.

Ubuntu is up to date through sudo apt-get update (and upgrade) and the Software Update app.  I have all Ubuntu Software sources from internet enabled (except source code - do I want that?).

I am a novice.  Are there any simple and straightforward troubleshooting steps I can take?

Memory - 3.7 Gb

Processor - Intel Pentium CPU N4200 @ 1.10 GHz x 4

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 4 (3.7) Gb is not enough.  Using the System Monitor, I could see that my RAM and Swap were both maxed out.  My Swap is only 1 Gb, so I will increase that to 4.